# Gradle: task with variable inputs

Tags: gradle, task, incremental-build

Is it a good idea for a task to get values from project properties or variables that can be changed. For example,

```
task mergeProperties {

    def propertiesFile = new File(project.ext.file1)
    def propertiesFile2 = new File(project.ext.file2)
    def outputFile = new File(project.ext.file3)

    inputs.files propertiesFile, propertiesFile2
    outputs.file outputFile

    doLast {
            // merge properties
    }
}
```

This method can be used to merge any two files and write to any file by changing property.ext properties. Is this a good idea? How UP_TO_DATE check works in this case?

Comment: As for any other task: by checking if the inputs (i.e. the contents of the two properties files) and the outputs (i.e. the contents of outputFile) has changed since the last execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: **No**

As long as you do not provide an example use case or scenario that needs the behaviour described above, I think it is a bad idea to let property files or command line values decide on execution logic. This is what code (in your `build.gradle`) should be about.

Also, `doLast` (and `doFirst`) closures are for minor preparation and cleanup jobs, the main task actions should be defined by a `@TaskAction` in the [custom task type](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/custom_tasks.html) definition:

```
class Merge extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def merge() {
        // merge properties
    }
}

task mergeProperties(type: Merge) {
    inputs.files 'myInputFile1', 'myInputFile2'
    outputs.file 'myOutputFile'
}
```

Now, a special scenario (I can't imagine right now) could use project properties to define the input and output files.